# How to play audio upon exiting a timer function the next part of the function?

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I'm trying to add a piece of audio that plays (only once!) when the timer reaches zero.

It's a Pomodoro timer, so the first timer goes down to zero, should play the audio, and then the next part of the same function 'break' should run:

```
function timer(){
    //Work Timer Countdown
    if(studySecs.innerText != 0){
        studySecs.innerText--;
    } else if(studyMins.innerText != 0 && studySecs.innerText == 0){
        studySecs.innerText = 59;
        studyMins.innerText--;
}

    //Break Timer Countdown
    if(studyMins.innerText == 0 && studySecs.innerText == 0){
        if(restSecs.innerText != 0){
            restSecs.innerText--;
        } else if(restMins.innerText != 0 && restSecs.innerText == 0){
            restSecs.innerText = 59;
            restMins.innerText--;
        } else {
          restMins == 0;
        restSecs == 0;
        alarm.play();
        }
    }


}
```

TLDR: I want to add 'alarm.play()' to run before the 'break timer' runs and I only want it to play once! Any advice?

Cheers!

Source code is roughly based on this:

https://github.com/learn-webdevYT/pomodoro-timer/blob/master/main.js

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is to use a  Promise that calls a callback once the timer reaches the end ;
the callback should be something like

```
function onEnd(){
  //play alarm
  alarm.play()
  //launch break timer
  timer(breakTime)
}
```